# Why doesn't x aesthetic remove missing values in multi-graph (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following below R code and sample data that together produce a combined plot with the help of the `gridExtra` package.

Now the issue is that whenever the `x` aesthetic that is shared among both graphs (`f.plot` & `sp.plot`) the `f.plot` does not crop/remove the missing values.

What causes this behaviour? I would like the `datadate` on the x-axis to start at the same observation in both graphs, so it is possible read the graphs together.

Below is the graph; as you can see the `datadate` for the top (`f.plot`) is leaving a large section blank. I would like this section to be removed so both charts show the same range for the `datadate`, the charts are then made comparable.

Thanks!

[image]

```
# My code
f.plot =   ggplot(f.DT,  aes(x = datadate)) +
             geom_point(aes(y = RSI_QEBIT,
                           colour = 'firm',
                           group = 1),
                        size = 1
                       ) +
             geom_point(aes(y = RSI_IWA.QEBIT,
                           colour = 'industry',
                           group = 2),
                        size = 1,
                        shape = 2
                        ) +
             scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, 90),
                                breaks = c(10, 30, 50, 70, 90)) +
             scale_colour_discrete(name = '') +
             ylab('RSI') +
             theme(legend.title.align = 0.5,
                   legend.position = 'top')

sp.plot = ggplot(f.DT, aes(x = datadate, y = Close)) +
            geom_line()

gridExtra::grid.arrange(f.plot, sp.plot, nrow = 2)

# Sample Data Below

> dput(f_sp.merged[[11]][, .(datadate, RSI_QEBIT, RSI_IWA.QEBIT, Close)])
structure(list(datadate = structure(c(10987, 11016, 11047, 11077, 
11108, 11138, 11169, 11200, 11230, 11261, 11291, 11322, 11353, 
11381, 11412, 11442, 11473, 11503, 11534, 11565, 11595, 11626, 
11656, 11687, 11687, 11718, 11746, 11777, 11807, 11807, 11838, 
11838, 11868, 11868, 11899, 11899, 11930, 11930, 11960, 11960, 
11991, 11991, 12021, 12021, 12052, 12052, 12083, 12083, 12111, 
12111, 12142, 12142, 12172, 12172, 12203, 12203, 12233, 12233, 
12264, 12264, 12295, 12295, 12325, 12325, 12356, 12356, 12386, 
12386, 12417, 12417, 12448, 12448, 12477, 12477, 12508, 12508, 
12538, 12538, 12569, 12569, 12599, 12599, 12630, 12630, 12630, 
12661, 12661, 12661, 12691, 12691, 12691, 12722, 12722, 12722, 
12752, 12752, 12752, 12783, 12783, 12783, 12814, 12814, 12814, 
12842, 12842, 12842, 12873, 12873, 12873, 12903, 12903, 12903, 
12934, 12934, 12934, 12964, 12964, 12964, 12995, 12995, 12995, 
13026, 13026, 13026, 13056, 13056, 13056, 13087, 13087, 13087, 
13117, 13117, 13117, 13148, 13148, 13148, 13179, 13179, 13179, 
13207, 13207, 13207, 13238, 13238, 13238, 13268, 13268, 13268, 
13299, 13299, 13299, 13329, 13329, 13329, 13360, 13360, 13360, 
13360, 13391, 13391, 13391, 13391, 13421, 13421, 13452, 13452, 
13482, 13482, 13513, 13513, 13544, 13544, 13572, 13572, 13603, 
13603, 13633, 13633, 13664, 13664, 13694, 13694, 13725, 13725, 
13756, 13756, 13786, 13786, 13817, 13817, 13847, 13847, 13878, 
13878, 13909, 13909, 13938, 13938, 13969, 13969, 13999, 13999, 
14030, 14030, 14060, 14060, 14091, 14091, 14122, 14122, 14152, 
14152, 14183, 14183, 14213, 14213, 14244, 14244, 14275, 14275, 
14303, 14303, 14334, 14334, 14364, 14364, 14395, 14395, 14425, 
14425, 14456, 14456, 14487, 14487, 14517, 14517, 14548, 14548, 
14578, 14578, 14609, 14609, 14640, 14640, 14668, 14668, 14699, 
14699, 14729, 14729, 14760, 14760, 14790, 14790, 14821, 14821, 
14852, 14852, 14882, 14882, 14913, 14913, 14943, 14943, 14974, 
14974, 15005, 15005, 15033, 15033, 15064, 15064, 15094, 15094, 
15125, 15125, 15155, 15155, 15186, 15186, 15217, 15217, 15247, 
15247, 15278, 15278, 15308, 15308, 15339, 15339, 15370, 15370, 
15399, 15399, 15430, 15430, 15460, 15460, 15491, 15491, 15521, 
15521, 15552, 15552, 15583, 15583, 15613, 15613, 15644, 15644, 
15674, 15674, 15705, 15705, 15736, 15736, 15764, 15764, 15795, 
15795, 15825, 15825, 15856, 15856, 15886, 15886, 15917, 15917, 
15948, 15948, 15978, 15978, 16009, 16009, 16039, 16039, 16070, 
16070, 16101, 16101, 16129, 16129, 16160, 16160, 16190, 16190, 
16221, 16221, 16251, 16251, 16282, 16282, 16313, 16313, 16343, 
16343, 16374, 16374, 16404, 16404, 16435, 16435, 16466, 16466, 
16494, 16494, 16525, 16525, 16555, 16555, 16586, 16586, 16616, 
16616, 16647, 16647, 16678, 16678, 16708, 16708, 16739, 16739, 
16769, 16769, 16800, 16800, 16831, 16831, 16860, 16860, 16891, 
16891, 16921, 16921, 16952, 16952, 16982, 16982, 17013, 17013, 
17044, 17044, 17074, 17074, 17105, 17105, 17135, 17135, 17166, 
17166, 17197, 17197, 17225, 17225, 17256, 17256, 17286, 17286, 
17317, 17317, 17347, 17347, 17378, 17378, 17409, 17409, 17439, 
17439, 17470, 17470, 17500, 17500, 17531, 17531, 17562, 17562, 
17590, 17590), class = "Date"), RSI_QEBIT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 52.3888128361573, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46.7695032956008, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.3242029313682, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.6760048140719, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.5228471731341, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.3099155797549, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32.7830014371969, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.7881826457913, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 64.3051398012505, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 70.4927002892185, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 74.92845166462, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 73.1828632792545, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 75.6616692267323, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 75.7182011312054, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 69.8912222101431, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 69.1474868532028, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 61.4827992057471, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 67.6521251778095, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60.5492221380302, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 58.4405381225396, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76.3950492398421, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.7475372075983, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46.7189968702056, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.4088861622833, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 52.5814996148601, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.1460913851499, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.9759786802541, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.2804111702118, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45.6344287258802, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.2833363940706, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.9207253278975, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54.1240920348388, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.0492784801673, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.4710534396005, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 52.4467450694257, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.02932538503, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 52.1689803368667, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.6667452399263, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 61.3320184022272, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 88.248988350591, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 61.0085510285969, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60.7285416584857, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.8003200216599, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.3532484143042, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.7791676198036, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), RSI_IWA.QEBIT = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 43.2784066785198, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41.4609583315373, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42.3458469721745, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41.3120415140818, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40.8593227567209, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41.7086142937269, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44.7672762897319, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44.4046311081346, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.644862711434, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 28.7570184940017, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32.8349550227414, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38.6602849808124, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37.2234181835582, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37.7007308226884, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38.4392137669943, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40.929862390392, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.06249604465, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.1896019911677, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45.7190353308931, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.5280841142112, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.9993266477174, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.213981475346, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 69.7758391275923, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 69.1848216836319, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 66.611224217245, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 65.3976647827331, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 63.7159220121554, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54.9970674178704, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 58.9788968609735, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 57.9755954312683, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 61.2711845632017, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54.3309207552518, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51.8480532753422, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39.7469823445025, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38.2532424695314, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44.9509307995001, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 33.7782129487646, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.7515721920479, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51.7879898400319, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51.645629213428, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.1117233066807, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41.5186301720134, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38.1568028154303, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42.5774975721961, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.3358004997924, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Close = c(16.1, 16.15, 16.9, 17.4, 18.7, 19.1, 
19.1, 19.85, 19.2, 19.7, 18.8, 19.2, 19.94, 20.1, 19.85, 21.65, 
20.34, 18.1, 18.87, 17.05, 15, 16.3, 14.01, NA, 14.22, 13.91, 
14.6, 16.13, 10.5, 16.4, 10.11, 15.3, 9.93, 15.05, 9.15, 14.55, 
9.73, 15.14, 9.37, 14.9, 8.9, 13.9, 8.91, 13.95, 9.27, 14.73, 
9.86, 14.96, 10.47, 15.5, 9.71, 14.25, 10.13, 14.47, 11.43, 15.6, 
12.83, 17.25, 11.69, 16.4, 12.61, 17.49, 12.81, 17.25, 13.12, 
17.33, 14.35, 18.67, 16.4, 21.25, 14.03, 18.56, 14.22, 19, 13.7, 
17.98, 13.18, 18.1, 13.13, 17.81, 13.98, 18.67, 14.95, 19.91, 
18.85, 15.7, 20.5, 18.2, 17.93, 22.67, 18.87, 17.44, 21.23, 18.89, 
20.37, 24.12, 19.05, 20.82, 24.93, 18.5, 20.75, 25.76, 18.95, 
21.56, 26.75, 18.88, 20, 24.03, 17.05, 20.17, 25.3, 17.24, 20.61, 
25.89, 17.5, 22.25, 27.2, 18.4, 23.4, 28.55, 18.86, 23.93, 28.39, 
19.45, 25.42, 29.5, 20.58, 21.75, 25.58, 18.5, 22.84, 26.65, 
21.35, 23.53, 27.41, 22.65, 24.96, 28.57, 23.2, 23.65, 26.76, 
21.99, 23.1, 26.88, 23.32, 24.45, 27.22, 23.87, 23.76, 26.07, 
24.8, 24.09, 26.7, 26.05, 22.32, 25.3, 25.3, 22.38, NA, NA, 25.56, 
23.19, 21.94, 19.62, 21.9, 19.6, 19.39, 17.04, 19.94, 17.21, 
19.85, 16.94, 19.98, 17.24, 19.45, 16.87, 19.11, 17.27, 19.92, 
18.73, 20.27, 19.09, 19.51, 18.3, 18.04, 17.06, 18.64, 18.84, 
18, 18.929, 18.11, 18.1, 17.62, 17.77, 17.67, 17.48, 18.35, 18.65, 
19.67, 19.1, 19.75, 19.71, 20.34, 20.53, 20.5, 20.11, 17.7, 17.31, 
18.85, 17.75, 15.99, 14.94, 13.01, 11.21, 11.24, 8.97, 9.35, 
7.62, 10.15, 8.31, 7.26, 5.64, 7.1, 5.58, 7.75, 6.57, 9.5, 8.76, 
9.18, 7.9, 8.78, 8.23, 9.4, 8.62, 11.33, 10.51, 10.26, 9.2, 10.13, 
9.61, 10.15, 9.63, 10.75, 10.1, 11, 10.45, 11.75, 11.66, 11.65, 
11.52, 10.09, 9.48, 9.73, 9.16, 9.93, 9.63, 10.33, 9.7, 11.34, 
11.06, 12.24, 11.99, 13.28, 12.89, 12.78, 12.86, 12.62, 12.69, 
12.5, 12.89, 13.41, 13.83, 13.36, 14.14, 12.78, 13.19, 12.15, 
12.58, 12.4, 12.95, 11.31, 11.55, 9.47, 8.99, 10.4, 10.45, 10.5, 
10.28, 10.76, 10.53, 10.05, 10.02, 10.09, 10.22, 9.35, 9.4, 8.88, 
8.97, 7.36, 7.09, 6.46, 6.37, 6.39, 6.37, 6.66, 6.77, 6.63, 6.74, 
5.99, 5.99, 5.17, 5.15, 4.95, 4.97, 4.55, 4.57, 4.39, 4.13, 5.18, 
5.1, 5.14, 5.06, 5.29, 5.08, 5.17, 4.93, 5.92, 5.78, 5.82, 5.5, 
6.06, 5.92, 6.7, 6.45, 6.56, 6.21, 6.57, 6.2, 7.2, 6.46, 7.46, 
6.74, 6.69, 6.08, 7.12, 6.5, 6.85, 6.33, 7.65, 7.18, 6.95, 6.4, 
6.93, 6.39, 5.87, 5.2, 4.55, 4.03, 3.72, 3.36, 3.66, 3.11, 3.4, 
2.68, 4.14, 3.32, 3.8, 2.99, 4.05, 3.36, 3.33, 2.67, 3.12, 2.49, 
2.09, 1.6, 1.93, 1.46, 1.14, 0.86, 1.28, 0.993, 1.14, 0.8626, 
1.02, 0.7332, 1.17, 0.83, 1.01, 0.7484, 1.7, 1.31, 2.06, 1.64, 
2.27, 1.75, 2.36, 1.84, 1.95, 1.5, 1.89, 1.44, 2.07, 1.59, 2.07, 
1.56, 2.04, 1.52, 1.93, 1.42, 1.63, 1.25, 1.56, 1.17, 1.33, 1, 
1.31, 0.985, 1.1, 0.8217, 1.02, 0.7904, 0.94, 0.72, 0.78, 0.6078, 
1.27, 1.03, 1.45, 1.08, 1.1, 0.8485, 1, 0.7946, 0.97, 0.77, 0.93, 
0.73)), .Names = c("datadate", "RSI_QEBIT", "RSI_IWA.QEBIT", 
"Close"), row.names = c(NA, -438L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10200f378>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range for `datadate` is basically from "2000-01-31" to "2018-02-28"

```
range(f.DT$datadate)
```

returns "2000-01-31" to "2018-02-28"

That's the reason your x-axis for the first plot assumes that range. You can change that using `xlim` or even better, actually just use data where there is no missing value (since that's what you want anyway).

Changing the value you pass to `data` so they only consider complete cases will yield:

```
ggplot(f.DT[complete.cases(f.DT),],  aes(x = datadate)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = RSI_QEBIT,
    colour = 'firm',
    group = 1),
    size = 1
)
```

Will fix the problem for you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why the range begins differently for the second plot?

Comment: No problem! In your original data the range begins from "2000-01-31" but if you only take the complete cases (omitting any rows of data where 1 or more columns contain NA) then the range starts from "2006-09-30"; In other words, the first and second plot only consider data from 2006-09-30 onwards because prior to that date no rows were "complete"

Comment: Yes. But without your addition (using complete.cases), the second graph  (i.e. the one with the close prices as y-axis) handles the data correctly, why this discrepancy?

Comment: Funny thing is without the intervention (complete cases), using exactly the code you pasted in the question, it didn't seem to handle it correctly for me. It tried to start plotting from the original start date as well! I have a very different plot from yours (second graph, with close prices as y-axis).

Comment: hmmm... interesting! Thank you for the valuable help. I suppose the easier choice is to use the complete.cases function when preparing to use ggplot2 for this type of setup.